# Were there any Vulcans serving on the Enterprise D?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, uss-enterprise

In the TNG episode *[The Enemy](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Enemy_%28episode%29)*, Worf ends up being the only viable donor available to save the life of an injured Romulan.

> Crusher: "Worf, you are the only one who can save his life."
>   Worf: "Then he will die."

Surely a Vulcan would be a superior match for obtaining vital bodily fluids. And with a crew compliment of 1,014 members there wasn't a single Vulcan serving on the Enterprise-D?

> Worf: "There is a substance within my cells which you need to survive."
>   Patahk: "Then you've come to hear me beg for my life?"
>   Worf: "No."
>   Patahk: "I would rather die than pollute my body with Klingon filth!"

Comment: Are you asking if one ever served on Enterprise D, or if one was serving only during that episode? For example, [Taurick](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Taurik) was seen serving on the Enterprise quite a while after that.

Comment: I was saying in general, because I had no memory of seeing any regular Vulcan crew member.

Comment: Does the Federation have a School for the Melodramatic Arts at Starfleet Academy?

Comment: The most likely explanation is that the Romulan had a Klingon as an ancestor, making him incompatible with Vulcan blood, but compatible with Klingon.

Comment: Or that all available Vulcans were of incompatible antigen (or equivalent) types.

Comment: ...During the episode in question, I have a vague memory of Crusher actually saying to Worf that Lt. Selar isn't a match...

Comment: Is the goal of this question to get a picture of every Vulcan that served on the Enterprise during its run? I don't think that is what the question is stating but it seems that is what everyone is interpreting the question to mean. I was assuming the question meant were there known Vulcans who were serving on the Enterprise during the time of this episode? (The answer is logically no, since if there were there would have been a more compatible match than Worf.)

Comment: "The Enemy" TNG, Episode 3x07, Production number: 40273-155, First aired: 6 November 1989

Comment: This Romulan seems like a right p'tach.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There were Vulcans on board during that episode, and they weren't compatible donors:

> CRUSHER: My patient is not responding to treatment.
>
> PICARD: You haven't found a compatible ribosome donor?
>
> CRUSHER: The lab is still processing the tests. Early results indicate humans have far too many bio-rejection factors. **I've also ruled out the Vulcans we've tested.**

The only direct explanation given for how Worf could be more compatible than the Vulcans is some vagueness about how "many humanoids have comparable cell structures."

Answer (score 14):

Lt. Selar, a Vulcan M.D., served onboard *Enterprise*.  She was first seen in the episode "The Schizoid Man."  She appears on the right in the image below.

[image: Kareen Brianon, Worf, and Selar]

Comment: "The Schizoid Man" TNG, Episode 2x06, Production number: 40272-131, First aired: 23 January 1989

Comment: Perhaps interestingly, the same actress would later play Worf's half-Klingon girlfriend.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, there were vulcans that served on Enterprise. However, only one example comes to mind presently.

[Taurik](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Taurik) served on board the Enterprise during the episode [Lower Decks](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Lower_Decks_%28episode%29), although this took place several years after the incident at Galorndon Core.

Comment: There was also [Lt. Selar](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Selar), who appeared in the second season and was mentioned sporadically through the rest of the series.

Comment: There's also a vulcan male in scant pattern uniform seen in the background of a shot during season 1. In Engineering yellow.

Answer (score 6):

### **Simplest answer:**

Even with a one thousand plus member crew, there is a distinct possibility there are NO other Vulcans onboard the Enterprise, AT THE TIME. Given the Vulcans relatively insular nature, it is not difficult to believe there may not be one onboard the Enterprise all the time, despite its flagship status.

- Like any other military or paramilitary force, the Federation moves its crewmembers from detachment to detachment on a regular basis.
- This improves the skills of the crewmembers and ensures a variety of skills being available and disseminated effectively.
- It also ensures cultural interactions, hopefully improving relationships between different social, cultural or species groups.
- The Vulcan who is capable of being a member of Starfleet is often just as desired by the Vulcan High Command, who will invoke Vulcan interests when their young adults consider Starfleet as a possible occupational choice.

### **Production Notes**

Checking the production notes for these episodes we discover there was a Vulcan medical officer named Lt. Selar who was around during the second season of TNG, appearing in "The Schizoid Man." By the third season when "The Enemy" is filmed, she is either no longer a crew member or on assignment somewhere else and unavailable.

- Selar was portrayed by Suzie Plakson and was only actually seen in TNG: "The Schizoid Man", although she was referenced many times throughout the series.
- "The Schizoid Man" TNG, Episode 2x06, Production number: 40272-131, First aired: 23 January 1989
- "The Enemy" TNG, Episode 3x07, Production number: 40273-155, First aired: 6 November 1989

Answer (score 1):

There was a Vulcan viola player in "Ensigns of Command", but it is unknown if he is Starfleet or civilian

[image]